# DATEADD() not working in sqlfiddle?

Tags: sql, dateadd, sqlfiddle

I am trying to return data from the past year from the current date, for example the table...

```
Orders

    OrderID CustomerID OrderDate
    1       23         2015-10-11
```

the OrderDate is in format date, 
I am using

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN (DATEADD(yyyy, -1, GETDATE())) AND (GETDATE());
```

But keep getting the error

```
FUNCTION db_9_9bcca.DATEADD does not exist
```

Does DATEADD() work with http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? Thanks.

Comment: please add which database server you want to use and which one you choose when creating the sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATEADD()` should work with sqlfiddle if you have specified an `MSSQL` Server in the DDL. I did so with the following DDL to build the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
 (OrderID int,
 CustomerID int,
 OrderDate date);
```

and ran the following query

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN (DATEADD(yyyy, -1, GETDATE())) AND (GETDATE());
```

and received the following result:

> Record Count: 0; Execution Time: ms